# Error: camera index out of range (hand gesture control drone with python)

Tags: python, opencv, mediapipe, tello-drone

I make hand gesture control with python. I'm using DJI TELLO DRONE. But my codes have Error with camera index out of range. Here is my code.

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
from djitellopy import tello


mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mp_drawing_styles = mp.solutions.drawing_styles
mp_hands = mp.solutions.hands
hands = mp_hands.Hands(model_complexity=0,min_detection_confidence=0.5,min_tracking_confidence=0.5,max_num_hands=1)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
width = 720
height = 280
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)
me = tello.Tello()
me.connect()
me.streamoff()
me.streamon()
isDroneFlying = False

def droneGestureController(image):
    image.flags.writeable = False
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    results = hands.process(image)
    image.flags.writeable = True
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    if results.multi_hand_landmarks:

        for hand_landmarks in results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, hand_landmarks, mp_hands.HAND_CONNECTIONS,
                                      mp_drawing_styles.get_default_hand_landmarks_style(),
                                      mp_drawing_styles.get_default_hand_connections_style())
            handlms = []

            c = 0
            for i in hand_landmarks.landmark:
                height, width, fc = image.shape
                x = (i.x) * width
                y = (i.y) * height
                handlms.append([c, int(x), int(y)])
                c = c + 1
            totalFingers = 0

            if (len(handlms) != 0):
                fingerTips = [8, 12, 16, 20]
                if(handlms[4][1]>handlms[3][1]):
                    totalFingers+=1

                for i in fingerTips:
                    if (handlms[i][2] < handlms[i - 2][2]):
                        totalFingers += 1

            droneAction = ""

            if (totalFingers==0):
                droneAction="Land"
                me.land()

            elif (totalFingers == 1):
                droneAction = "Move forward"
                me.send_rc_control(0,30,0,0)

            elif (totalFingers == 2):
                droneAction = "Move backward"
                me.send_rc_control(0, -30, 0, 0)

            elif (totalFingers == 3):
                droneAction = "Left"
                me.send_rc_control(-30, 0, 0, 0)

            elif(totalFingers == 4):
                droneAction = "Right"
                me.send_rc_control(30, 0, 0, 0)

            elif(totalFingers==5):
                droneAction = "Takeoff"
                me.takeoff()
                me.send_rc_control(0, 0, 50, 0)

            else:
                droneAction = "No Action"

            cv2.putText(image, droneAction+" "+str(totalFingers), (10, 25), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 0, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
            return [image,handlms]
        return [image,[0]]
    return [image,[0]]

while True:
    try:
        success, image = cap.read()
        droneImage = me.get_frame_read().frame
        droneImage = cv2.resize(droneImage, (360, 240))
        image = droneGestureController(image)[0]
        isDroneFlying = True
        cv2.imshow('YourPC', image)
        cv2.imshow('Drone', droneImage)
        k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        if k == 27:
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
    except:
        continue
cap.release()
```

And here is my error message:

> '[ERROR:0@0.909] global obsensor_uvc_stream_channel.cpp:156 cv::obsensor::getStreamChannelGroup Camera index out of range'

What's the problem with my code?

I tried `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` to change `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)` but it didn't work.
I also tried adding this import `from pathlib import Path` but it didn't work too.

Comment: that DJI Tello thing isn't a USB webcam.